# ruby issue with float point iteration

Tags: ruby, floating-point

When I run the code

```
count = 0

while count < 1
  count += 0.1
  puts count
end
```

I would expect

```
0.1 
0.2 
0.3 
. . .
```

I have however been getting

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.7999999999999999
0.8999999999999999
0.9999999999999999
1.0999999999999999
```

can anyone help explain this?

Comment: Search Stack Overflow for questions about floating point precision. There are lots of answers already. Here’s one that I wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512650/strange-output-when-using-float-instead-of-double/28512770#28512770

Comment: I STRONGLY encourage you to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Hint: don't repeatedly add 0.1 - instead, increment an *integer* by 1 then at each step, multiply by 0.1. You will still have a similar problem, but you'll get *less* rounding error. Have a look at "[*Is floating point math broken?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1364007)" for a **very** detailed discussion of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way:

Your computer only has 32 or 64 bits to represent a number. That means it can only represent a finite amount of numbers.

Now consider all the decimal values between 0 and 1. There is an infinite amount of them. How can you possibly represent all Real Numbers if your machine can't even represent all the numbers between 0 and 1?

The answer is that your machine needs to approximate decimal numbers. This is what you are seeing.

Of course [there are libraries that try to overcome these limitations](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) and make it so that you can still accurately represent decimal numbers. One such library is BigDecimal:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

count = BigDecimal.new("0")
while count < 1
  count += 0.1
  puts count.to_s('F')
end
```

The downfall is that these libraries are generally slower at arithmetic, because they are a software layer above the CPU doing these calculations.

Comment: Using `Rational` would be easier.

Comment: Doesn't `BigDecimal` have the same problem as `Float` (but just causes the problem to appear later)?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. It cannot represent all values exactly. However you can set the precision you require, and then use it for specific calculations within that precision level with confidence - that's what makes it much more useful than working with simply floating point values.

Comment: @sawa: In short, no.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, this leads to many surprising situations.

I advise to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You may want to use [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many consequences of the representation of floating point number in memory !

To explain what exactly is is happening would be very long, and has other people have already done it better before, the best thing for you would be to read about go read about it elsewhere :

- The very good  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (article from 1991, reprint on oracle)
- Wikipedia pages [Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) and [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)
- [IEEE 754 References](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/References.xhtml)

You can also have a look at those previous questions on SO:

- [What is a simple example of floating point/rounding error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error)
- [Ruby BigDecimal sanity check (floating point newb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039650/ruby-bigdecimal-sanity-check-floating-point-newb)
- [Strange output when using float instead of double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512650/strange-output-when-using-float-instead-of-double/28512770#28512770)